# Looping Selector for windows Universal apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, loopingselector

I am trying to implement the `LoopingSelector` for Windows Universal app based on this [source](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api).

When I try to convert the app to a Universal app, it seems there is no `LoopingSelector` control for Universal Apps.

Is there a `LoopingSelector` control or equivalent for usage in a Universal app?